# What's the returning a value in Java?

Tags: java, return-type

```
public void warning(){
    System.out.println("Watch out!");
}
```

---

```
public void warning(){
    System.out.println("Watch out!");
    return;
}
```

---

We must use "return" statement with void methods. Bot of these bring same output. What's the difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You needn't use `return` with void methods in Java, although some coding conventions may call for it, it is not a requirement of the language.  Semantically they behave exactly the same way, as the "end" of a void method is an implicit return.

Now, it is also possible to put a `return;` in a conditional block (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc...) where it might exit the method early. For example:

```
void someMethod() {
   if (this.avoidSomething) {
       return;
   }
   System.out.println("Something not avoided.");
}
```